# Can't access "request" object in a JSP unless I qualify it as pageContext.request?

Tags: jsp, el

I'm trying to access a query parameter within a JSP.  Using `request.getParameter( )` directly doesn't work, but using `pageContext.request.getParameter( )` works as expected.  It seems that the implicit `request` object is not directly available, despite what the docs suggest.

I can work around this as shown, but would like to know why this is not working as expected.

My JSP code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test.jsp</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <jsp:text>param.username=${param.username}</jsp:text>
        <br/>
        <jsp:text>pageContext.request.getParameter("username")=${pageContext.request.getParameter("username")}</jsp:text>
        <br/>
        <jsp:text>request.getParameter("username")=${request.getParameter("username")}</jsp:text>
        <br/>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty request}">
                <jsp:text>request is empty!</jsp:text>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <jsp:text>request is NOT empty!</jsp:text>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <br/>
        Using a scriptlet, request.getParameter("username")=<%= request.getParameter("username") %>
        <br/>
        Using a "jsp:expression" tag, request.getParameter("username")=<jsp:expression>request.getParameter("username")</jsp:expression>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the result of loading this page is as follows, using a URL of `http://localhost:8080/jsp_fun/test.jsp?username=roy`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test.jsp</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        param.username=roy
        <br/>
        pageContext.request.getParameter("username")=roy
        <br/>
        request.getParameter("username")=
        <br/>
        request is empty!
        <br/>
        Using a scriptlet, request.getParameter("username")=roy
        <br/>
        Using a "jsp:expression" tag, request.getParameter("username")=roy
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look closely at the generated HTML and compare it to the JSP, you can see that `request.getParameter( )` doesn't work but `pageContext.request.getParameter( )` does.  As well, checking to see if request is empty indicates that it is empty/null, so the rest of the results are consistent (if wrong and annoying, IMHO).

And for reference, my code is deployed to Tomcat 8.0.32, and I am using the following JSTL lib via Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looking at the generated java code in Tomcat's work/Catalina dir, I see the following interesting lines of code, showing the different ways that the request object is referenced, depending on my source JSP:

```
  out.write("        param.username=");
  out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${param.username}", java.lang.String.class, (javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null));
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("        <br/>\n");
  out.write("        pageContext.request.getParameter(\"username\")=");
  out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${pageContext.request.getParameter(\"username\")}", java.lang.String.class, (javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null));
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("        <br/>\n");
  out.write("        request.getParameter(\"username\")=");
  out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${request.getParameter(\"username\")}", java.lang.String.class, (javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null));
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("        <br/>\n");
  out.write("        ");
  if (_jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(_jspx_page_context))
    return;
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("        <br/>\n");
  out.write("        Using a scriptlet, request.getParameter(\"username\")=");
  out.print( request.getParameter("username") );
  out.write("\n");
  out.write("        <br/>\n");
  out.write("        Using a \"jsp:expression\" tag, request.getParameter(\"username\")=");
  out.print(request.getParameter("username"));
```

Any thoughts on why I can't directly reference the `request` object as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind-- looking at the real docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij, the request object is NOT supposed to be available directly-- it is supposed to be a child of the pageContext object.  The tutorials I was looking at are all wrong in stating that the request object is directly accessible.

Comment: The request object is directly accessible from scriptlets, but not in expression-language expressions.